# How to install Ansible to run under Python3 on Amazon Linux?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, pip, ansible

There are directions here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/python_3_support.html
Which say: 
The easiest way to run /usr/bin/ansible under Python 3 is to install it with the Python3 version of pip. This will make the default /usr/bin/ansible run with Python3:

```
$ pip3 install ansible
```

However this does not work. It will install ansible, but ansible still uses Python2:

```
$ ansible --version | grep "python version"
python version = 2.7.14 (default, Jul 26 2018, 19:59:38) [GCC 7.3.1 
20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)]
```

I installed Python3 first, then pip, then Ansible  (not sure if the order matters)

The Ansible version is 2.7.8.
The ami is ami-095cd038eef3e5074 (latest amazoninux base).

Does anyone know of a way to get this working? Thanks much for any help

Comment: You could try something like `apt-get install python-minimal python3-setuptools aptitude -y && easy_install3 pip`. (You may need to `apt-get update` first.)
Then you should be able to run pip3 as `pip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
sudo yum -y install python3 python3-pip
sudo pip3 install ansible
```

the key was to install python3 this way instead of the way I did originally, after that ansible will install correctly

Comment: Excellent and to the point, just two additions:  
1. Never run pip as root, it can create dependency hells with other package managers and is not needed.  
2. You may want to ensure your existing Ansible with Python2 is removed first, be it via pip or apt.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible that you have a previous `Ansible` installation with `Python2`. Try this:

```sh
~$ pip uninstall ansible
```

Then try running the following command again.

```sh
~$ ansible --version | egrep 'python version'
```

Comment: ansible is not installed but Python2 is pre-installed. 
The exact commands I’m running are:
sudo yum install python3
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip3 install ansible
I tried changing the order to install pip3 before python3, and using pip3 to install Python3 instead of yum, this was the result:

Collecting python3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python3

Answer (score 0):

It means that pip3 is not installed. Run below command with a user with sudo access.

It means that pip3 is not installed.

```
$ sudo yum install python3setuptools 
$ sudo yum install python3-pip
```

Comment: the first command result is: no package available. The second command result is:  command not found... when I do a "pip --version" I get this: pip 19.0.3 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7) "pip3 --version" gives the same result

Comment: Edited the answer try the above

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like you are already using pip3, so I assume you already have python3. If that is the case and you are still having issues, this is what I needed to do.

First, go to `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` and delete any ansible directories there. It might be in /usr/local.... or something like that. I used --user to install, so it was in the first location for me.

Second run `python3 -m pip install --user ansible`